# Can Oauth2 replace session (or other similar means) to keep user login information at server side?

Tags: session, oauth-2.0

I'm a little new to this and please bear with me if I ask dumb questions.

As what I know, session is something saved at server (either in file or in database), and client access it via sessionid saved in cookie. To keep user login information, we can simply put a 'logged_in' column and an 'expired' column in session file or session table.

As far as I know, Oauth2.0 is designed for third party client to access the server. The whole process is controlled by an access_token, which is quite similar to sessionid (at least from my knowledge).

So, here's my question, is it possible to use Oauth2.0 to completely replace session? I.e., even people are using the website designed by me (NOT third party website) to access my own server? So that I have a unified authorization framework for user accesses both from my own website and any thrid party website.

Is there any pros&cons of using session & oauth 2.0?

Lastly, how about mobile app? I know for third party mobile app, they normally use oauth to access the server (many websites provides oauth api). How about if I am going to write my own app for my own server (NOT third party)? Does Oauth 2.0 apply here too?

To summarize, my question is actually is, is Oauth 2.0 universal that can be used in all kinds of user authorization control situations from all kinds of devices?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both are short-living entities, session IDs and OAuth tokens are fundamentally different and used for distinct scenarios. A session is used to identify a user of a web application, thus related to the end user. An OAuth token is used to grant access to a third-party service to access a limited set of protected user resources (e.g. read user contact information or send a mail from the user account). Though the token refers to the granter (i.e. end user authorized the grant), the token related more to the third-party application.

To give you an analogous example: imagine that you have a safe at your bank (i.e. your protected resource). The session is your id for the bank: give it to someone else and he will be you, he can get everything from your safe. On the other hand, a token is a limited authorization to someone else to your safe: e.g. your approval that he can get 10$ from your safe while a security guard is watching.

As a summary, sessions and tokens are not interchangable.